# Good database/plug-in to scrape for academic paper info?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the web to find information about a set of academic papers.

Unfortunately, for many of the papers, I only have the author's name, a year, and part of a title.

(For example, [BANDURA A, 1997, SELF EFFICACY EXERCI])

I have tried using a web driver to look up the papers on Scopus but many of the papers are not there.

Does anyone know of a good academic paper database and/or plug-in that I could search through using the information I have?

Is there a better way to solve this problem?